# JSON fields containing '@' in TypeScript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

In Angular project, using TypeScript, I am trying to present some JSON fields received from POST request to the user.

One of the fields starts with the '@' character, which happen to be a reserved word in Angular so

```
this.timestamp=response.@timestamp
```

Results with compile error -

> Identifier expected

How do I escape the said character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [bracket property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#:%7E:text=object.propertyName-,object%5Bexpression%5D,-Copy%20to%20Clipboard).

```
this.timestamp=response['@timestamp']
```

Comment: In general, try to avoid this kind of symbols in front of property. Tough to maintain